# VS Code running on RHEL 8 is throwing a unable to write program user data error

Tags: visual-studio-code

This occurs when logging into a RHEL 8 host as one user, then opening a terminal and doing a switch user(su) to switch to another user account, the launching code. The error is attached to this post. VS Code is installed systems wide for all users.

I tried as the user that I logged in as and vs code launched without error.

Comment: "_The error is attached to this post._" ... where?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a complicated Unix issue.  Eliding the details, the issue is that your connection to the graphics desktop is tied to your login username.  If you run an application as another user, that application does not have permission to connect to your graphics desktop.

If you run the command `xhost +` (AS the login user), that turns off the permission checking and should allow you do to what you want.